# Is there a way to detect if a custom module exists?

Tags: javascript, dojo

Dojo 1.10+

I want to conditionally load custom module according to this post

[Dojo FAQ: How can I conditionally load AMD modules?](https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2014/02/25/dojo-faq-how-can-i-conditionally-load-amd-modules/)

```
require([
    'dojo/has'
], function (has) {
    var ui;
    var moduleId = 'myApp/ui/';

    // Assume 'has' tests for mobile and tablet
    // have been defined
    if (has('mobile')) {
        moduleId += 'Mobile';
    }
    else if (has('tablet')) {
        moduleId += 'Tablet';
    }
    else {
        moduleId += 'Desktop';
    }

    require([moduleId], function (UiModule) {
        ui = new UiModule();
        ui.placeAt(document.body);
        ui.startup();
    });
});
```

However it seems dojo/has only detects certain dojo features.  If that is the case is there an alternative method to detect if a custom module exists before attempting to require and then instantiate it if its a widget?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [dojo/has](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/has.html) only detects certain dojo features. But you can add your own, i was trying something like you are trying here, maybe not the best, but this work for me.

At boot time of your app, you can add you own features to dojo, i.e.

```
var deviceWidth = has('device-width'), hasTouch = has('touch');

has.add('mobile', (hasTouch && deviceWidth <=736));

has.add('tablet', (hasTouch && (deviceWidth > 736 && deviceWidth <=1024)));
```

and so on, so, later in another widget, you can require `dojo/has` and use the recently added features. Or event better, you can do this

```
require(['dojo/has!mobile?myApp/ui/Mobile:myApp/ui/Tablet'], function (UiModule) {
    ui = new UiModule();
    ui.placeAt(document.body);
    ui.startup();
});
```

I've never tried nested `dojo/has` validations and i can not tell you if it works, but i've tried like in the example i'm giving you and it works.

Think that you can have in your project your own `has` lib extending the `dojo` version and adding all the features you want. For example:

```
//myApp/has.js
define(["dojo/has"], function(has){
    has.add('myApp', true);

    return has;
});.
```

Then later in your app you can include `myApp/has` and us it just like if it were the `dojo` version.